# Readiness Check gives Found non-writable path(s): /home/USER/DOCROOT/php.ini.sample

Tags: upgrade, security, magento-2.1.1

Want to update Magento 2.1.1. to new 2.1.2. for security

Readiness check gives:

> Check Cron Scripts Cron script readiness check failed. Hide detail
>
> Error from Updater Application Cron Script:
>
> Found non-writable path(s): /home/USER/DOCROOT/php.ini.sample
>
> For additional assistance, see cron scripts help.

But when I check php.ini.sample doesn't exist

Nowhere really good to find this answer

Who knows and can help?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like php.ini.sample cannot be *created*. Is `/home/USER/DOCROOT/` writable?

Comment: Thanks @fschmengler Now all checks are green, but when upgrading , update stays pending, nothing happening, waiting for hours, any idea?

Answer (score 3):

<sub>From the comments, because it solved the original problem:</sub>

Sounds like `php.ini.sample` cannot be created. Make sure that `/home/USER/DOCROOT/` is writable.